# How to send allure or html report as an attachment in the Jenkins email notifications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, allure, email-notifications, html-reports-jenkins

How to send allure or html report as an attachment in the Jenkins email notifications. This is example of the pipeline i am using in my Pipeline script in Jenkins. I have setup my email notifcations, however i want to get some sort of report in the email. Please note that providing a link is not enough because my tests are setup on a different machine with the reports.

```
pipeline {  
     agent any  
     stages {  
         stage('Test') {  
             steps {  
                 sh 'echo "Fail!"; exit 1'  
             }  
         }  
     }  
     post {  
         always {  
             echo 'This will always run'  
         }  
         success {  
             echo 'This will run only if successful'  
         }  
         failure {  
             mail bcc: '', body: "<b>Example</b><br>Project: ${env.JOB_NAME} <br>Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} <br> URL de build: ${env.BUILD_URL}", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "ERROR CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}", to: "foo@foomail.com";  
         }  
         unstable {  
             echo 'This will run only if the run was marked as unstable'  
         }  
         changed {  
             echo 'This will run only if the state of the Pipeline has changed'  
             echo 'For example, if the Pipeline was previously failing but is now successful'  
         }  
     }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `emailext` plugin not `mail`

```
failure {
  emailext(
    attachmentsPattern: "<path to report>", 
    body: '', 
    subject: "", 
    to: ""
  )
}
```

Comment: i tried to add this path of the allure report but it is not attaching the report in the email. My report is saved here - $WORKSPACE/${env.HOME}/app/target/allure-results